# Modify an array of object using ES6 Pure function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am modifying an array of object using pure function but facing some challenge to modify userDetails object.

My requirement is instead **1**, I need to show **true** inside **permissions** object. Please check my code and suggest. I know, I am doing some small mistake but still trying to identify.

I dont want main data source should get affected. Please suggest if you have any other good option

```js
let data = [
      { id: 1, 
        title: 'admin1', 
        permissions: { 
          userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null}, 
          salaryList: { abc: 1, def: 2, asdf: 0, poi: 1}
        }
      },
      { id: 1, 
        title: 'admin1', 
        permissions: { 
          userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null}, 
          salaryList: { abc: 0, def: 1, asdf: null, poi: 0,wew: 1, aaa: 1}
        }
      },
    ]

    let modifiedObjs = data.map( record => {
    
      return {
        id: record.id,
        title: record.title + " Edited Object",
        permissions: handlePermission(record.permissions)
      }
    })
    
    function handlePermission(permissions){
      Object.keys(permissions).forEach((key)=> {
        Object.keys(permissions[key]).forEach((obj) => {
          if(permissions[key][obj]===null){
            delete permissions[key][obj]
          }else{
            const value = permissions[key][obj];
            const finalV = value === 0? false : value ===1? true : value === 2 ? null : value;
            permissions[key][obj] = finalV
          }
        })
      })
      
      return permissions
    }

console.log(data, "main data")
console.log(modifiedObjs, "modified data")
```

Comment: This ternary chain is really ugly and hard to read. I'd go for switch.

Comment: can you use es6 and above features or es6 and below only?

Comment: I want to use es6 and above features

Comment: I would recommend to copy the permissions first and make `handlePermission` a pure function too. (return it at the end). Then maybe you can simplify a little bit the ternary like: `value ===  0? false : value === 1 ? true: null` (could you have more than those 3 values?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that `permissions` is a reference inside of `handlePermission`, meaning that when you `delete` from it, it will also the key will also be removed from your original object (as they're sharing the same reference). One way to fix this is to instead build a *new* object. Whenever you find a key you want to keep, you can add it to the new object. Then, instead of deleting, you can simply not add the key/value to the object.

See example below:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, title: 'admin1', permissions: { userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null }, salaryList: { abc: 1, def: 2, asdf: 0, poi: 1 } } }, { id: 1, title: 'admin1', permissions: { userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null }, salaryList: { abc: 0, def: 1, asdf: null, poi: 0, wew: 1, aaa: 1 } } }, ];

let modifiedObjs = data.map( record => {
  return {
    id: record.id,
    title: record.title + " Edited Object",
    permissions: handlePermission(record.permissions)
  }
});

function handlePermission(permissions){
  const newPermissions = {};
  Object.keys(permissions).forEach((key)=> {
    newPermissions[key] = {}; // set object for key
    Object.keys(permissions[key]).forEach((obj) => {
      if(permissions[key][obj]!==null){
        const value = permissions[key][obj];
        const finalV = value === 0? false : value ===1? true : value === 2 ? null : value;
        newPermissions[key][obj] = finalV;
      }
    });
  });
  
  return newPermissions;
}

console.log(data, "main data")
console.log(modifiedObjs, "modified data")
```

I would instead approach it like so, which uses [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a `[key, value]` pair array of entries from your object, along with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to reconstruct the object after its values have been [mapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)/[filtered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, title: 'admin1', permissions: { userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null }, salaryList: { abc: 1, def: 2, asdf: 0, poi: 1 } } }, { id: 1, title: 'admin1', permissions: { userDetails: { activeUser: 1, team: null }, salaryList: { abc: 0, def: 1, asdf: null, poi: 0, wew: 1, aaa: 1 } } }, ];

const modifiedObjs = data.map(({id, title, permissions}) => ({
  id,
  title: title + " Edited Object",
  permissions: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(permissions).map(([key, obj]) => [
    key,
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([,v]) => v !== null)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v > 1 ? null : !!v]))
  ]))
}));

console.log(data, "main data");
console.log(modifiedObjs, "modified data");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick but can we use ES6 rather than Object.fromEntires so that number of line will be more understandable and less. Please guide

Comment: @AnandDeepSingh see the first snippet for ES6 way (a modified version of your solution). Object.fromEntries() can be achieved using other methods such as `reduce` &/or `Object.assign` which are ES6, but that will add even more complexity to the `.map()` method. Is there a particular issue with using Object.fromEntries()? You seemed to be fine with using ES6+ features [when I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139097/modify-an-array-of-object-using-es6-pure-function/64139652#comment113420101_64139097)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. You have superb knowledge of JS. Loved you solution. Actually I am trying to achieve same but stuck with this approach